# How do I create JSON file structure and then populate through jq with bash output

Tags: json, bash, jq

Trying to create the following JSON structure through bash. There will be a max of 4 environments that I want to be shown even if there are no content within them, and example output can be found below the structure.

Example General Structure:

```
{
    "ENV":{
        "ENV1":{
            "Middleware": [
                {
                "value1": "",
                "value2": ""
                
            }
        ],
            "System": [
                {
                "value1": "",
                "value2": "",
                "value3": ""
            }
        ],
            "Application": [
                {
                "value1": "",
                "value2": ""
            }
        ], 
            "Utility":[
                {
                "value1": "",
                "value2": "",
                "value3": ""
            }
        ] 
        },
        "ENV2":{
            "Middleware": [
                {
                "value1": "",
                "value2": ""
                
            }
        ],
            "System": [
                {
                "value1": "",
                "value2": "",
                "value3": ""
            }
        ],
            "Application": [
                {
                "value1": "",
                "value2": ""
            }
        ], 
            "Utility":[
                {
                "value1": "",
                "value2": "",
                "value3": ""
            }
        ]
        },
        "ENV3":{
            "Middleware": [
                {
                "value1": "",
                "value2": ""
                
            }
        ],
            "System": [
                {
                "value1": "",
                "value2": "",
                "value3": ""
            }
        ],
            "Application": [
                {
                "value1": "",
                "value2": ""
            }
        ], 
            "Utility":[
                {
                "value1": "",
                "value2": "",
                "value3": ""
            }
        ]
        },
        "ENV4":{
            "Middleware": [
                {
                "value1": "",
                "value2": ""
                
            }
        ],
            "System": [
                {
                "value1": "",
                "value2": "",
                "value3": ""
            }
        ],
            "Application": [
                {
                "value1": "",
                "value2": ""
            }
        ], 
            "Utility":[
                {
                "value1": "",
                "value2": "",
                "value3": ""
            }
        ]
        }
    }
}
```

Example json output (output.json):

```
{
    "ENV": {
        "ENV1": {
            "Middleware": [
                {
                    "value1": "Mqwerty",
                    "value2": "Mqwerty"
                },
                {
                    "value1": "Mqwerty",
                    "value2": "Mqwerty"
                },
                {
                    "value1": "Mqwerty",
                    "value2": "Mqwerty"
                }
            ],
            "System": [
                {
                    "value1": "Sqwerty",
                    "value2": "Sqwerty",
                    "value3": "Sqwerty"
                }
            ],
            "Application": [
                {
                    "value1": "Aqwerty",
                    "value2": "Aqwerty"
                },
                {
                    "value1": "Aqwerty",
                    "value2": "Aqwerty"
                }
            ],
            "Utility": [
                {
                    "value1": "Uqwerty",
                    "value2": "Uqwerty",
                    "value3": "Uqwerty"
                }
            ]
        },
        "ENV2": {
            "Middleware": [],
            "System": [],
            "Application": [],
            "Utility": []
        },
        "ENV3": {
            "Middleware": [
                {
                    "value1": "Mqwerty",
                    "value2": "Mqwerty"
                },
                {
                    "value1": "Mqwerty",
                    "value2": "Mqwerty"
                }
            ],
            "System": [],
            "Application": [],
            "Utility": []
        },
        "ENV4": {
            "Middleware": [],
            "System": [],
            "Application": [],
            "Utility": []
        }
    }
}
```

My input file will look something like this (input.txt):

```
ENV1,Middleware,Mqwerty,Mqwerty
ENV1,Middleware,Mqwerty,Mqwerty
ENV1,Middleware,Mqwerty,Mqwerty
ENV1,System,Sqwerty,Sqwerty,Sqwerty
ENV1,Application,Aqwerty,Aqwerty
ENV1,Application,Aqwerty,Aqwerty
ENV1,Utility,Uqwerty,Uqwerty,Uqwerty
ENV3,Middleware,Mqwerty,Mqwerty
ENV3,Middleware,Mqwerty,Mqwerty
```

I would like to use jq to create the aforementioned structure and then populate the json file with the values in the input file. Also, a secondary question is that after the json file is produced, can you edit or partially update certain components of the file? E.g. Changing ENV.ENV1.Middleware[0].value1 from Mqwerty to Cqwerty without recreating the whole file.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Since SO is not a free programming service, questions such as yours are generally expected to be accompanied by an example of what you've tried, with a focus on a particular issue. 
 You can rest assured that everything you've described can be done quite easily using jq, so any time you spend learning jq will not be wasted.

Comment: Hi @peak , I'm extremely confused as to where to go and even looking at some resources. I've tried the following:

`jq -R -n '(inputs | split(",")) |
{"ENV":{(.[0]):""}}'<<<"$fileinput" `

What the goal with the above line was to produce the top level being "ENV" and then have objects created under it. I know the issue with the above code is that each index of the produced array is creating a new environment object. I'm not sure as to how to start off with 1 ENV object and create nested objects within it through jq language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple solution:

```
< input.txt jq -nR '
  reduce (inputs | split(",")) as $line ({};
    getpath($line[0:2]) as $v
    | setpath($line[0:2]; $v + [{value1: $line[2], value2: $line[3]} ] ) )
'
```

Comment: Hi @peak , thank you so much for all the help! Right now I'm having difficulty adding logic where if its an "application", it'll have 3 keys instead of 2. The key structure is as follows: If an Application, then it'll have domain, host and user as keys instead of "value1" and "value2". Something like the following structure is what I'm targeting:

"Application" (keys):
- domain
- host
- user
"Utility"
- domain
- health
- version
"Middleware"
- name
- release
"System"
- name
- tag

Cheers, really appreciate the aid.

Comment: It seems you just need to branch, e.g. on the number items in $line.

Comment: Not too sure as to what changes need to be made. My current code is looking like below:

`#!/usr/bin/jq -Rnf
reduce inputs as $line
  ( .ENV
    ["DEV", "SIT", "UAT", "PROD"]
    ["Middleware", "System", "Application", "Utility"] = []

  ; ($line | split(",")) as $elements
  | .ENV [$elements[0]] [$elements[1]] +=
    [ $elements[2]
    
    ]
  )`

However, I'm not sure how to change this to get the key structure I'm looking for.

Comment: It seems you have a significantly different question from the one originally posted.  Accordingly it might be best if you ask a new SO question in accordance with the [mcve] guidelines.